# Can I use Modelsim license for Student Edition 10.6 for Altera Modelsim 16.0 edition?

Tags: modelsim, intel-fpga

I have the license for Modelsim 10.6 SE. Can I use the same license for Altera-Modelsim 16.0 (latest version)?

Comment: The latest Altera-Modelsim edition is 10.5c (actually, ModelSim-Intel FPGA 10.5c).

Comment: @Qiu That's right. I was looking at the latest version of Quartus which comes as a bundle with Modelsim in it. I assumed the Modelsim version to be 16.0 but internally they are using 10.5c. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think that the answer for your question is buried here:

> The ModelSim - Intel FPGA Edition software requires a valid license. This license expires 15 months after the date of purchase. Every 15 months you must regenerate your license file in the Self-Service Licensing Center to renew your license for the specific ModelSim-Intel FPGA Edition software version that you purchased. **The ModelSim - Intel FPGA Edition software does not require a separate license file. If you purchase this software, your Quartus Prime license file includes a FEATURE line to enable it.** You must, however, specify the location of license file for the ModelSim Intel FPGA Edition software using an environment variable before you can use it. Refer to the topic about specifying a ModelSim license file for more information.

Source: [Intel® FPGA Software Installation and Licensing](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/manual/quartus_install.pdf)

> Q: Is the ModelSim-Intel FPGA Edition software the same as the ModelSim PE/DE software?
>
> A: **No.** ModelSim-Intel FPGA Edition software only supports our gate-level libraries. The ModelSim-Intel FPGA Edition software includes the base features of ModelSim PE, including behavioral simulation, HDL testbenches, and Tcl scripting. However, ModelSim PE optional features are not supported in the ModelSim-Intel FPGA Edition software and the simulation performance of the ModelSim-Intel FPGA Edition software is slower than that of the ModelSim PE/DE software.

Source: https://www.altera.com/products/design-software/model---simulation/modelsim-altera-software.html#note2

But the easiest way to verify that would be to install ModelSim-Intel and test it.